# Unix Script For Telling The Day

Tags: bash, shell-script

I need a script that will tell me what day it is when I type a number
representing the number of days since Sunday.
e.g.

- 0 = Sunday
- 6 = Saturday
- 9 = Tuesday
- 130 = Thursday

I guess this will need some while loops but don't know how to start it off,

Comment: `date '+%j'` you will return the current day from the year. 

You can find more info here: http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/coreutils#Date-conversion-specifiers

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -A dow
dow[0]="Sunday"
dow[1]="Monday"
dow[2]="Tuesday"
dow[3]="Wednesday"
dow[4]="Thursday"
dow[5]="Friday"
dow[6]="Saturday"

echo ${dow[$(($@%7))]}
```

Use dict in bash is concise enough. You can also use python to write this script, which will be:

```
#!/bin/env python
import sys
dow={}
dow[0]="Sunday"
dow[1]="Monday"
dow[2]="Tuesday"
dow[3]="Wednesday"
dow[4]="Thursday"
dow[5]="Friday"
dow[6]="Saturday"
print(dow[int(sys.argv[1])%7])
```

As Tonchev said, this script assumes that the first day of any year is always Sunday, which is derived from the question. But we can do better, sure:

```
#!/bin/bash
date -d "${1}0101 +$2 days -1 day" +%A
```

Since we find `date` can do a better job, the old script used dict could be changed to:

```
#!/bin/bash
date -d "Sunday +$1 days" +%A
```

Comment: And according to your solution the 130th day of the year what day is it?

Comment: @SvetlinTonchev It's Thursday, anything wrong?

Comment: Yes, the 130th day of 2015 is May 10 (Sun) . The reason your calculation is not correct is because your "year" always starts in Sunday. But if it starts in Wed or Fri? Also if its a leap year?

Comment: You are right, I have update my answer, thanks for pointing this out, and I came out with a new solution!

Answer (score 1):

Using GNU `date`:

```
$ days=130
$ date -d "Sunday +$days days" "+%A"
Thursday
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [Euclidean division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_division), e.g.:

```
% echo $(( 130 % 7 ))
4
```

or

```
% dow=$(( 9 % 7 )) 
% echo $dow
2
```